# Unable to connect from on-prem network using work laptop to Azure VM

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

In my company, I have setup an Azure VM and selected a pre-defined VNet (associated with a subscription). I then added inbound rules on the newly created NSG allowing ports 80, 443 and 3389(rdp).
The VM has ubuntu and apache2 installed and when I browse vm's localhost the default apache page shows.

However, when I browse the VM site from my laptop via company network, I get a connection timeout error on the browser.

I used Azure - IP verify tool and fond the cause, it appears to be a rule created for isolating NSG by the Admin team, thus blocking all inbound traffic (see image below). I cannot remote this rule.

To override this rule, I created an inbound rule at NSG level with higher priority but it still does not 
work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

### [image]

Edit: I am able to RDP to my VM without any issues, the main issue is to do with browsing the website hosted in my VM from the company network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

For your issue, you could ensure to add an inbound security rule with a higher priority than the rule 4090 like this: destination port `80,433` with action `allow` and priority 100. If there are two NSGs in the **networking** of the virtual machine: one is associated with NIC, the other is associated with a subnet, you should allow port 80,443 in both NSGs.

[image]

As far as I know, the UFW firewall is inactive on the Azure VM by default. If you enable it, you could adjust the firewall to allows HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

After that, you could run `telnet VM's public IP 80` in the CMD on the laptop to verify if the networking connection is normal. If not, contact the admin in your company to allow the outgoing traffic for port 80 or 443 or something else like virus software on your laptop is blocking it.

If the above all is no effect, you could restart your azure VM on the Azure portal. Sometimes, it may take effect on accessing the website outside of Azure. You also could follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-lamp-stack#verify-installation-and-configuration): Install a LAMP web server on a Linux virtual machine in Azure.

Comment: Hi Nancy, thanks for your answer.  I wasn't clear in my question that the RDP was working for me, the issue was with port 80 and 443 where I could not browse the website from my company network.

Comment: Hi Nancy, Sorry for the delay in responding to you. I didn't think about the NSG of the subnet. It didn't allow 80 and 443. Unfortunately, I do not have enough rights to add an inbound rule directly to subnet, I will need to request this.  Thanks very much for your detailed response. I will get a rule added and update here.

Comment: Yes, finally I was able to get the Inbound rule set on the NSG of the subnet. The connection is working now. @nancy-xiong many thanks for the help!!